# Hive Regexp_Extract failing

Tags: regex, hive

Any idea why this is unable to parse?

select regexp_extract(product_list, 'eVar7=(\?![^;]*?unav)', 1) 
    from table1

Getting  back the following error:

FAILED: ParseException line 1:45 cannot recognize input near '?' '!' '[' in expression specification

Answer (score 2):

Hive requires you to escape semicolons in string literals. Theoretically, it should be possible to not require this, but the parsing of string literals is somewhat divorced from the splitting of input into different statements. Anyway, try this:

```
select regexp_extract(product_list, 'eVar7=(\?![^\;]*?unav)', 1) from table1
```